# Is it always a good idea to ask for password requirements?

Tags: passwords

Creating a form with password we can obligate users to insert a password that complaints a regular expression. But is it a good idea to ask for this requirements? Something like to have at last 8 characters, 2 special simbols, 2 numbers, etc...
What I mean is that maybe sign ups can increase if we let users free to write the password they wish with no restrictions.

Can someone explain me if in this case there are security issues?

Comment: By allowing the user to create weak passwords the security issue will be that the password is easy to guess and hack the user account - stealing whatever info is stored there and/or performing any actions from there on the user's behalf. If you only care about signups number and not security...Well, I wouldn't use such a "service".

Comment: So why a web site like Facebook doesn't ask for a password with special requirements?